# Bitmap Constructor URL VS image, how to decide?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, easeljs, createjs

I am wondering about performance in such a scenario where there could be 100 Bitmap element on stage.

If I constructed those bitmaps using URL, would each bitmap tries to download the image file from the URL regardless the fact that they all use the same image URL?

And, if I use an image to construct those bitmaps, I will have to download the image only once, so, all bitmaps will use the same image? so, when to use the URL?

I would appreciate it if someone clarifies the difference between two approaches in-term of memory and bandwidth utilization, when to use each one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL is only requested once, no matter how often you create a Bitmap with the same URL, so it won't make a difference from that perspective.

However the difference is, if you use an URL to instanciate a Bitmap the first time, you (very likely) have to wait until the image is loaded, and then update the stage to display it.

Update: I've made a quick jsfiddle: http://bit.ly/10Xavkf  if you take a look at the network-tab you can see that the image is only requested once.

Comment: Thanks, so isn't there a difference from memory perspective?

Comment: No, the memory-perspective should be the least of all issues, because your browser will/should take care of not caching an image with the same URL twice. - However if you create 100 instances of a bitmap, it is the convention and much better code if you preloaded that image.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, by the way, I found that using an image is more robust than using URL, specially for IE, sometimes I am forced to use a loaded image instead of URL to make it work, even for chrome ..

Comment: Yes, I'd recommend you to use URL only for quick tryouts, not for production-code